# How to reduce size of several photos in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to leave a feedback on aliexpress.com, but this site does not accept photos larger than 5 MB. Can I write a simple bash script to reduce size of several photos at the same time?

```
for file in *.JPG; do echo 'reduce size image here'; done
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for img in *.JPG; do
        convert "$img" -resize "1280x960>" $(basename "$img" .JPG)_new.jpg
done
```

here is the pixel format for photo size less than 5 MB

```
Image Dimensions in Pixels  Printed Size (W x H)    Approximate File Size (CMYK Tiff)
1024 x 768 pixels           3.41" x 2.56"           3 Mb
1280 x 960 pixels           4.27" x 3.20            4.7 Mb
```

convert is from ImageMagick. ">" says it's only resized if larger. See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) for its other options.

Comment: It works, but correct: `convert "$img" -resize "1280x960>" $(basename "$img" .JPG)_new.jpg`

Comment: There should be no backticks `\`` around the `convert` command and you can avoid the unnecessary *command substitution* by replacing `$(basename "$img" .JPG)_new.jpg` with `"${img%.JPG}_new.jpg"` and use the parameter expansion instead (POSIX).